# Docker / multiple architectures in different stages of a Multi-Stage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build, buildx, multiarch

I want to build a docker image for aarch64 and an intermediate stage ist to cross compile an application using another stage which builds an amd64 build environment. A simple example works as expected:

```
FROM alpine AS base
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file1
EOF

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 alpine AS cross_build_image
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file2
EOF

FROM base AS release
COPY --from=cross_build_image example_file2 .
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
EOF
```

running this with:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 --target release --tag release_image --no-cache --progress=plain .
```

outputs:

```
#10 [cross_build_image2/2] RUN <<EOF (uname -a...)
#10 0.058 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 Linux
#10 DONE 0.1s

#11 [base 2/2] RUN <<EOF (echo uname -a...)
#11 0.088 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 Linux
#11 DONE 0.1s

#12 [release 1/2] COPY --from=cross_build_image example_file2 .
#12 DONE 0.1s

#13 [release 2/2] RUN <<EOF (echo uname -a...)
#13 0.087 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 Linux
#13 DONE 0.1s
```

As you can see, cross_build_image runs correctly with x86_64 and the release is build using aarch64.

But this does not work anymore with the following construct:

```
FROM alpine AS base
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file1
EOF

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 base AS cross_build_image
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file2
EOF

FROM base AS release
COPY --from=cross_build_image example_file2.
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
EOF
```

Now it does the following:

```
#8 [base 2/2] RUN <<EOF (echo uname -a...)
#8 0.075 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 Linux
#8 DONE 0.1s

#9 [cross_build_image 1/1] RUN <<EOF (echo uname -a...)
#9 0.088 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 Linux
#9 DONE 0.1s

#10 [release 1/2] COPY --from=cross_build_image example_file2.
#10 DONE 0.0s

#11 [release 2/2] RUN <<EOF (echo uname -a...)
#11 0.091 Linux buildkitsandbox 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 aarch64 Linux
#11 DONE 0.1s
```

As you can see, now everything is built using aarch64. This is not what I expected. But the cross_build_image shall use the same base as the release image, only with different architectures. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "alpine" is a multi platform image, so stages that reference alpine directly can use the appropriate platform. "base" is an image you are building, and you have specified one platform "linux/arm64". As you have not specified amd64 in the list of platforms, the `FROM --platform=... base` directive is pointless.

Comment: I thought the --platform=linux/amd64 would be propagated down to the base stage, so that the base stage is also built using --platform=linux/amd64. Everything else makes no sense to me, because otherwise it is not possible to reuse any stage for both architectures.

Comment: As you can see in the first example it works to specify a different platform for cross_build_image, though buildx is called with --platform linux/arm64. So it would also be possible to build base with both architectures if it was smart enough to propagate down the platform to base, in dependence of the platform of the "parent" stage. Building release image would then built base 2 times with different platforms.

Comment: But this seems not to work that way, so I have no idea how to achieve that the cross_build_image has the same base as the release. The only idea is to build cross_build_image with a separate "docker buildx build", so that it can be used directly, but hmm, that's not the way I expected multi-stage builds can be done.

Comment: I haven't done multistage Multiplatform builds but things are not going to pass upwards. If you specify `FROM alpine AS base` then its going to build `base` with whatever explicit platforms you have provided. later stages then make use of what's available.

Comment: OK. Tomorrow i will try this:  FROM --platform=linux/amd64,Linux/arm64 alpine AS base. Maybe then the different stages choose the right base. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Does also not work :(

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to create one image with binaries from both platforms like this? You could drop the cross_build_image and pass --patform twice to docker buildx build to simply get a multi platform image.

Comment: I don't want to create a multiplatform image. I want to create an image which runs on an ARM platform and this image only needs my application and all runtime dependencys. But: the application has to be compiled first and the compilation has to be done on a x86 host via cross compilation. This cross compilation toolchain resides in a x86 docker image. The whole build process of the ARM docker image has to be done on a x86 host. Running a native ARM toolchain on an x86 host via docker buildkit would be too slow, because it uses qemu.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the only (not that nice) solution is this:

```
FROM alpine AS base
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file1
EOF

# same installation content AS base
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 alpine AS base_clone
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file1
EOF

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 base_clone AS cross_build_image
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  touch example_file2
EOF

FROM base AS release
COPY --from=cross_build_image example_file2 .
RUN <<EOF
  uname -a
  ls -la
EOF
```

running this with:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 --target release --tag release_image --no-cache --progress=plain .
```

This works finally, but you have to code repeat the base.